# Join array and leave delimiter in string using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

Is it possible to join an array of strings and insert the a delimiter on all elements?

For example:

```
%w[you me].join(" hi-") => "you hi-me" # expected "hi-you hi-me"
```

Comment: You can't `split` an array. You can `split` files and Strings.

Comment: Try using join instead of split.  Play with it in IRB

Comment: What do you want the return value to be? An array of strings or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `split` an array. You can `split` files and Strings.

If you're talking about splitting a string:

```
'now-is-the-time'.split(/-/) # => ["now", "is", "the", "time"]
```

Using a pattern that captures the delimiter/splitter will return the delimiter in the results:

```
'now-is-the-time'.split(/(-)/) # => ["now", "-", "is", "-", "the", "-", "time"]
```

---

> Sorry, I got confused. I want to join an array into a string.

You can't selectively join, but you can insert text between elements in an array:

```
%w[foo bar].join(' he-') # => "foo he-bar"
```

You can prepend your "join" text:

```
ary = %w[foo bar foo bar]
join_text = ' he-'
join_text + ary.join(join_text) # => " he-foo he-bar he-foo he-bar"
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry, I got confused. I want to join an array into a string.

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. Please reword it so it is clear.

Comment: I just updated the question again. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you need is something like:

```
%w[you me].map {|s| s != "hi" ? "hi-#{s}": s }.join(' ')     => "hi-you hi-me"

%w[hi you me].map {|s| s != "hi" ? "hi-#{s}": s }.join(' ')  => "hi hi-you hi-me"
```

**Edit** :

Now that you have changed your question, the test is not useful anymore.

This will do:

```
%w[you me].map {|s| "hi-#{s}" }.join(' ')     => "hi-you hi-me"
```

Comment: I've updated the question again, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda version:

```
ary      = %w[foo bar foo bar]
add_text = ->x{' he-'+x} 
p ary.map(&add_text).join #=> " he-foo he-bar he-foo he-bar"
```